# how to set up a cdn?

Tags: caching, dns, cdn

I just bought a cdn from ovh.ie for my website example.com

Here are the instructions. however, i am unable to set up it. Can someone guide me on how to set it up step by step?

1) Report the Backends (IP of your servers) ;

2) Declare the domain/sub-domains that you want to intergrate with the CDN ;

3) Point your domain to the CNAME created after your domain is registered;

4) Add your first cache rule.

Adding a domain on the CDN generates a CNAME with the format yourdomain.ext.web.cdn.anycast.me, you need to point the DNS of yourdomain.ext to this CNAME to activate it.

Once configured, a time delay is necessary so that all of your CDNs are operational. Otherwise, it will reach its full performance with progressive caching as set by your rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the DNS details for yourdomain.ext so that it points to yourdomain.ext.web.cdn.anycast.me for example.

There are typically two types of DNS records that you need to worry about, A records which point to an IP address and CNAMEs which point to a URL.

The root/apex of a domain can only point to an IP on most systems.
The root domain in your case is example.com and can only use an A record.

Subdomains can use both CNAME's and A records.

Apex A record example (example.com):

```
Hostname    Type     Target
--------    ----     ---------------------------------
@           CNAME    1.1.1.1
```

WWW subdomain CNAME example (www.example.com):

```
Hostname    Type     Target
--------    ----     ---------------------------------
www         CNAME    yourdomain.ext.web.cdn.anycast.me
```

The advantage of using the cname is it can hold a number of IPs that can change, if you simple pointed your site at one of their IP addresses they could disable it and take your site down, so it you are given a URL always use a CNAME to it instead of an A record to an IP.

This is why many websites use WWW.example.com or subdomain.example.com.

It is worth noting that using a cname as an apex is not RFC compliant and some hosts do not allow it or offer an alternative proprietary record type to achieve this on their internal system.

Another way around this if your nameserver provider is RFC compliant is to have to apex be an A record and point to a page with a redirect to the CDN or to use a service like wwwizer.

[DNS Glossary](https://pop.co/glossary)